# Textview letter spacing issue

Tags: android, android-xml, android-drawable, android-textview-autosize

- I am trying a display a single letter on a `TextView`.
- Here `TextView` is having a `background drawable` with a border but `TextView` expands and shrinks based on that single letter and I don't want that.

[image]

My layout code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="4dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_letter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/drawable_bg"
    android:fontFamily="@font/viga"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_16dp"
    android:text="A"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />
```

**drawable_bg.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#F5F5F5" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#9E9E9E" />

    <corners android:radius="4dp" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="8dp"
        android:left="20dp"
        android:right="20dp"
        android:top="8dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `wrap_content` so the size is change according to the text. Simply use fixed dimension

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_letter"
    android:layout_width="20dp"   // fixed size
    android:layout_height="20dp"  // fixed size
    android:background="@drawable/drawable_bg"
    android:fontFamily="@font/viga"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_16dp"
    android:text="A"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />
```